# Net Present Value - Numpy vs Excel

Tags: python, excel

I am taking a course in Coursera and am boggled by a simple NPV function.

**Question:**

> What is the present value of $4,000 per year annuity for 8 years at an interest rate of 6%?

**Excel:**

`=NPV(6%, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000,  4000, 4000)`

=$24,839

**Numpy_Financial:**

```
npf.npv(0.06, [4000 for i in range(8)])
```

=$26,329

The excel answer is accepted as correct, and there do not seem to be any viable parameters in numpy_financial NPV function. Does anyone know how to get excel's value in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/npv-function-8672cb67-2576-4d07-b67b-ac28acf2a568) assumes that the first value is at t=1 (no initial wealth), while [numpy-financial](https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/latest/npv.html?highlight=net%20present%20value) assumes the first value to be at t=0. Therefore, In numpy you start with an initial wealth of 4000 and your result is basically the excel result * 1.06.

If you want to calculate the excel result using numpy, set the initial wealth to zero:

```
npf.npv(0.06, [0] + [4000 for i in range(8)])
```